# duplicate key value in sql anywhere and sql server

Tags: key, duplicates

I have a powerbuilder datawindow that must work with both sqlanywhere and sql server for one of our apps. the table datawindow is attached to in both dbms has a primary key unique column. When I insert a new row the driver or the database in sqlanywhere passes a value that is not already in the table but when same insert is done against sql server it passes value 1 which is already in the table and hence the insert fails. I know this may be a question related to sql server and powerbuilder but I couldn't find any answers anywhere so i thought I will ask it here and may be someone had experienced it before.

thanks

Comment: What does your insert SQL statement look like?

Comment: the insert stat is created by the datawindow and it has the value for the column that complains abt the dup key, I cannot see the value for sqla but sql server value is 1 and that value is already there

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my own problem, after spending the whole day on it. We were generating the unique key for the column I was having problem inserting value in sql server via a before insert trigger (sql anywhere allows that). This trigger was actually calculating the unique key before insert was sent to dbms and it was calculating the key correctly. However that same trigger when implemented in sql server via 'instead of insert' trigger (sql server allows that) was failing to calculate the unique key because of a bug in it. Once I fixed it that solved the problem. Powerbuilder datawindow itself had nothing to do with it and was passing the initial value set for that column (if there was an initial value) to the dbms. I hope this will help